# Can PC harm my earphone/ head set comes with mobile phone

Tags: audio, headset, headphone-jack

I have been using a Samsung Galaxy S7 (http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s7-7821.php). My computer is a Dell PptiPlex-7040. (http://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/productdetails/optiplex-7040-desktop).

1. Will computer emit more power (Voltage or Amperage) through its line out (Usually designed in green color) compared to the phone?
2. Is it safe to plug above-mentioned earphone (with a 3.5mm jack) to the computer? Will that damage the earphone/ headset

Comment: The 3.5mm jack has the same specifications cross platforms. Your earphones will not become damaged if you use it for your computer.

Comment: Is there any possibility for a PC to output more power compared to a mobile phone, which can harm the listening device? From my personal experience I could hear louder through my PC. That's why I am wondering. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: There's a big difference in sound output on different platforms and sound cards, specially in quality. A computer can typically boost the volume with various software or drivers, but in the end, the earphone itself would not be a problem. I would be more concerned with my ears to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on the quality of the speaker.

It's possible to blow a cheap speaker with many audio sources. It's hard to blow a nice speaker even with a high powered amplifier.

1. = NO
2. = It is safe but anything is possible.

How much is this earphone worth? Can you not afford to replace it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is the original handsfree, which had bundled with the phone

Comment: So did you plug it in? How does it sound?

Comment: Yes, I did. I did not any issues other than boosting bass. When I increase the bass effect, I experienced a distortion.

Comment: Yeah, those things generally can't reproduce bass. So is this question resolved?